# Rails: Use of 'foreign_key'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a City model and Cities table. Service model and Services table.
A service has one city (origin city and destiny city). And a city 'has many' services.
In the services table, it has two columns about the city: origin_city_id and destiny_city_id. But just one model and one table about city.

How do I create a relationship between this two tables/models?

I want to use this two fields (origin and destiny cities) in the input form, when the admin creates the service

The started code:

- City model: has_many :service
- Service model: belongs_to :city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to setup your models in the following manner

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :origin_services, class_name: 'Service', foreign_key: :origin_city_id
  has_many :destination_services, class_name: 'Service', foreign_key: :destiny_city_id
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin_city, class_name: 'City'
  belongs_to :destiny_city, class_name: 'City'
end
```

Comment: Do I need to use :origin_services or can I use just :service in the 'has_many'?

Comment: Depending on the version of Rails you're using you should be able to do `has_many :services, -> (city){ where("services.origin_city_id=? OR services.destiny_city_id=?", city.id, city.id) }` if you just want the single `has_many` association on `City`.